# Vue.js with pinia npm server error variable is assigned a value but never used

Tags: vue.js, npm, pinia

I am using this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ok6vO98RV_Q&t=108s, but I keep getting the error: "error  'counter' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars". What am I missing?

```
<template>
      {{ counter }}
</template>

<script>
import { storeToRefs } from "pinia";
import useStore from "../store/useStore";

const main = useStore;
const { counter } = storeToRefs(main);
</script>
```

store:

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
// import { auth } from "./auth.module";

export const useStore = defineStore("main", {
  state: () => ({
    counter: null,
  }),
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify [`<script setup>`](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html) for Composition API or else you have to expose the properties manually to the template by returning them.

```
<template>
      {{ counter }}
</template>

<script setup>
import { storeToRefs } from "pinia";
import useStore from "../store/useStore";

const main = useStore();
const { counter } = storeToRefs(main);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Do you have an idea, why I get an "Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function" error on the line const main = useStore(); ?

Comment: Nevermind, I removed the brackets, now  it's ok. :)